# Проблема с авторизацией на сайте

Tags: php, авторизация

Такая беда, форма входа есть на каждой странице сайта, если я захожу в свой аккаунт с главной страницы (index.php), то авторизация работает нормально и на всех страницах я появляюсь как авторизованный.
Если я зашел в полное описание новости к примеру, (mysite.ru/category/php/write/1/), и ввел данные авторизации на этой странице, то только на ней я появляюсь как авторизованный пользователь, на остальных страницах меня опять просит ввести логин и пароль. В чем проблема? Прикладываю код, он инклудится на каждой странице сайта.

> ```
>  session_start();
> //Проверка на авторизацию
> if (isset($_COOKIE['l']) && isset($_COOKIE['i']))
> {
>   $id_user = $_COOKIE['i'];
>   $login_user = $_COOKIE['l'];
>   $ip_user = $_COOKIE['ip'];
> }
> //Авторизация
> if(isset($_REQUEST['ok']))
> {
>   //Получение данных из формы
>   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
>   {
>       $l_login = clearData($_POST['l_login']);
>       $l_password = hash('sha1', mysql_real_escape_string(trim(strip_tags($_POST['l_password']))));   
>   }
>
>   //Запрос на получение данных пользователя
>   $query_login = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='$l_login' AND
> ```
>
> password='$l_password'";
>       $query_answer = mysql_query($query_login);
>       $logIn = mysql_fetch_array($query_answer);
>
> ```
>   //Объявляем нужные переменные
>   $browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
>   $time = time();
>   $id_user = $logIn['id_user'];
>   $pass_user = $logIn['password'];
>   $login_user = $logIn['login'];
>   $ip_user = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
>
>   if($l_login == $login_user AND $l_password == $pass_user)
>   {
>       setcookie('ip', md5($user_ip), time() +3600*24);    
>       setcookie('l', $login_user, time() +3600*24);
>       setcookie('i', $id_user, time() +3600*24);
>       $_SESSION['login'] = $login_user; 
>       $_SESSION['id'] = $id_user;
>       mysql_query("INSERT INTO session (id_user,time,ip,browser) VALUE
> ```
>
> ('$id_user','$time','$ip_user','$browser')");
>       }
>
> ```
>   if($_POST['remember'] == 'on')
>   {
>       setcookie('ip', md5($user_ip), time() +3600*24*7);  
>       setcookie('l', $login_user, time() +3600*24*7);
>       setcookie('i', $id_user, time() +3600*24*7);
>   }
>   echo "<html><head><meta    http-equiv='Refresh' content='0;
> ```
>
> URL=/index.php'></head></html>";
>     }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
isset($_COOKIE['i'])
```

А можно использовать сессии. куки не всегда работают.

Comment: Позвольте уточнить, про какие сессии идёт речь ? если вы про session_start - так они тоже через куки работают ;)

Comment: При успешной авторизации выдаешь к примеру
<pre><code>
$_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;

if ( $_SESSION['loggedIn'] == true ) {
авторизован 
} else {
не авторизован
}</code></pre>

Comment: @shurik только Куки хранятся у пользователя а сессии хранятся на серваке, в чем разница рассказать и почему именно сессии а не куки у пользователя?

Comment: Ну расскажите :) Буду рад выслушать :)

Что бы не быть голословным сразу приложу своё пояснение:

session_start между прочим тоже создаёт куку. По умолчанию это PHPSESSION в которой хранится идентификатор сессии. А сама сессия уже хранится на сервере. Т.е мы передаём серверу некий ключ по которому и подымается наша сессия. Но кука должна существовать.

А ваша фраза:

>> А можно использовать сессии. куки не всегда работают.

не совсем верна.

За сим откланиваюсь.

Comment: Вот именно, Блин вчитайтесь в текст!

Я И имею ввиду СЕССИЮ а не хранение всех нужных переменных в КУКАХ, session_start() подразумевает куку или подстановку в URL значения PHPSESSID, но не куки(мн.число)! и это и есть разница, не путать.